# Storing vertex data in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, raytracing, vertex

I'm trying to create a real time raytracer using OpenCL. I would like to provide an option to create something similar to VBO in OpenGL and then render them with different transformations, materials and so on. In order to implement this I need to store this data and add new models. After thinking a lot I have decided to organize everything like this: there is a single buffer `(global char*)` for all models
[image]

Every model is a part of this buffer and consists of *spheres*, *triangles* and *texture coordinates* (their count is 0 if texture is not needed).
When we want to create a model on host, we call `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` with a proper offset. 
Now when we want to render a scene, we fill another buffer which is called 'Render list'. Each entry of this buffer contains a pointer to a model (offset in array of models), material info and transformation (translation and rotation). Render list is cleared (or overwritten) before each frame.
Given all this information we are able now to render a scene in the kernel. But this solution seems too messy, too sophisticated. 
Is it a good way to implement a flexible raytracer? Are there any common practices in OpenCL to do things like that which are better?

Comment: Take a look at other ray tracers such as http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/LuxRays